# Silex User with multi roles from database

Tags: php, symfony, roles, silex, user-roles

i have silex project with my SecurityServiceProvider like:

```
$this->app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
            'security.firewalls' => array(
                'login' => array(
                    'pattern' => '^/login$',
                ),
                'secured' => [
                    'pattern' => '^/admin.*$',
                    'anonymous' => true,
                    'form' => array(
                        'login_path' => '/login',
                        'check_path' => '/admin/auth'
                    ),
                    'logout' => array(
                        'logout_path' => '/admin/logout'
                    ),
                    'users' => $this->app->share(function() use ($self) {
                        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler($self->app['db']);
                    }),
                ]
            ),
            'security.role_hierarchy' => [
                'ROLE_USER' => [],
                'ROLE_BACKEND_USER' => ['ROLE_USER'],
                'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => ['ROLE_USER','ROLE_BACKEND_USER']
            ],
            'security.access_rules' => array(
                ['^/.*$', 'ROLE_USER'],
                ['^/admin.*$', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'],
                ['^/admin.*$', 'ROLE_BACKEND_USER']
            )
        ));
```

Now i have a DB Table with a list of roles:

```
22  ROLE_ACCESS_NODES_DELETE
23  ROLE_ACCESS_NODES_STATUS
24  ROLE_ACCESS_NEWSLETTERS_SEND
25  ROLE_USER
26  ROLE_BACKEND_USER
```

My users are stored in a DB table, then I have other table for user/role relations.

How can i load these roles and apply to my user?

Thanks

Comment: where do you store users and how do you assign roles to users?

Comment: @MaxP. My users are stored in a DB table, then I have other table for user/role relations.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [writing custom user provider in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html). The same [applies to Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider) as well.

You basically have to write a custom `User` class and `UserProvider` that loads the user by their username and then can fetch any additional data you might need.
In your case, you'll also load user rights from the database, add them to some property in `User` object that can be later retrieved by Symfony2 using [UserInterface::getRoles()](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html#method_getRoles).